# Why are wrong images getting loaded in ListView occasionally?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-download-manager, getview

I have a listview which loads images in every cell in async. When I try to scroll down slowly(after all the images in the current view are loaded), it works flawlessly. 
But when I try to scroll down before they are even loaded and scroll up, I face this issue. The cells start to show up images which don't correspond to them.

My getView method looks like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View rowView = null;

    if(convertView == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_posts_item, null);
        final Holder holder=new Holder();
        holder.tvTitle=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleNamePost);
        holder.ivPrimaryImage=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivPrimaryImage);
        holder.tvLocality=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocalityPosts);
        holder.tvDateCreated=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateCreated);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        rowView=convertView;
    }

    Holder holder = (Holder)rowView.getTag();
    holder.ivPrimaryImage.setId(position);
    holder.ivPrimaryImage.setTag(listOfPosts.get(position).getPostId());
    holder.ivPrimaryImage.setImageBitmap(null); // Added for flickering issue
    holder.tvTitle.setText(listOfPosts.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvLocality.setText(listOfPosts.get(position).getLocality());
    holder.tvDateCreated.setText(listOfPosts.get(position).getCreatedDate());
    postId = listOfPosts.get(position).getPostId();
    Image image = new Image();
    image.setImg(holder.ivPrimaryImage);

    if (!"N".equalsIgnoreCase(listOfPosts.get(position).getHasImage()) ) {
        if(!tagsCaching.containsKey(postId))
            new GetPrimaryImages().execute(image);
        else
             holder.ivPrimaryImage.setImageBitmap(tagsCaching.get(postId));
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

And my Async call class looks like this:

```
public class GetPrimaryImages extends AsyncTask<Image, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView imageView = null;
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Image... images) {
    this.imageView=images[0].getImg();



        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postid",(String)(this.imageView.getTag()) ));


             json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CommonResources.getURL("get_primary_image"),
                    "POST", params);


        if(json == null){
            return null;
        }
        Log.d("Fetching Image",imageView.getTag()+ json.toString());
        tagsDownloaded.add((String)imageView.getTag());
        // check for success tag
        String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 0) {
               image =  json.getString("primaryimage");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return getImage(image);

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        tagsCaching.put((String)imageView.getTag(), result);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);

    }

    public Bitmap getImage(String imageString) {
        if("null".equalsIgnoreCase(imageString)){
            return null;
        }else{
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            //image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            return decodedByte;
        }

    }


}
```

Edit:

I added a new instance variable to Holder:

```
public class Holder
{
    TextView tvTitle;
    ImageView ivPrimaryImage;
    TextView tvLocality;
    TextView tvDateCreated;
    int position;
}
```

Set the same in the getView:
    holder.position = position;
And passed the holder object to the Async task:
    new GetPrimaryImages(position, holder).execute(image);

And modified the Async call class as follows:
1. Added cancel to the http call
2. Changed the onPostExecute method

```
  public class GetPrimaryImages extends AsyncTask<Image, Void, Bitmap> {

    int mPosition;
    Holder mHolder;
    public GetPrimaryImages(int position, Holder holder){
        mPosition = position;
        mHolder = holder;
    }

    ImageView imageView = null;
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Image... images) {
    this.imageView=images[0].getImg();



        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postid",(String)(this.imageView.getTag()) ));


        JSONObject json;
        if(mHolder.position == mPosition)
             json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CommonResources.getURL("get_primary_image"),
                    "POST", params);

        else {
            json = null;
            cancel(true);
        }

        // check log cat fro response
        if(json == null){
            return null;
        }
        Log.d("Fetching Image",imageView.getTag()+ json.toString());
        tagsDownloaded.add((String)imageView.getTag());
        // check for success tag
        String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 0) {
               image =  json.getString("primaryimage");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return getImage(image);

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
            tagsCaching.put((String) imageView.getTag(), result);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }

    public Bitmap getImage(String imageString) {


        //needs to wait
        if("null".equalsIgnoreCase(imageString)){
            return null;
        }else{
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            //image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            return decodedByte;
        }

    }


}
```

It seems to be working. :)

Now my doubt is what would be the best way to cache the images? Should be writing it to a file? and reading it from it every time I scroll up?

Comment: yet another "if without else" in getView( [view reusing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) )  + wrong timing with AsyncTask (what if asynctask finished after view will be reused?) ... **answer: learn about view reusing in ListView and use any of image loaders library out there**

Comment: @Selvin It looks like wrong timing is the issue. How to sync it with Async task?
Or is there a way to skip the Async task for views which are getting reused?

Comment: use LIBRARY, most of 'em are cancelling background loading if you set new request ... it is not so easy(feel free to take a look at the sources)  ... you skills are to low to build own loader ... also `if (!"N" ...` is without `else` ....

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, while your async task ends its background operation, the element it was linked to has been recycled to hold another element of your collection.

Let's focus on elements position, and let's say your listview can display up to 4 elements.

The first time the listview calls getview for the first 4 elements, and four asynctasks are created and run. 
Then you scroll to shouw positions 11 - 15, and the first element (the one related to position 1) gets recycled for position 11 before the asynctask ends.

Then the asynctask ends, and what you see is the image related to post 11 with the bitmap related to post 1.

A way to avoid this is knowing in the asynctask that the view was recycled, as suggested in this old post from Lucas Rocha.

[Performance tips with listview](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

Check the post for insights on how listview works too:

[image]

Comment: @fedpaol
I changed the following in my async call and it seems to be working
if(mHolder.position == mPosition)
                 json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CommonResources.getURL("get_primary_image"),
                        "POST", params);

            else {
                json = null;
                cancel(true);
            }
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
                tagsCaching.put((String) imageView.getTag(), result);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            }

        }
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Main "problem" is with ListViews implementation of reusing views and serial providing of AsyncTasks.

1) In ListView's adapter you correctly implement reusing of items. In ListView there are rendered only few items (items visible on screen + few top and down). If you start scrolling items which went out of screen are destroyed and theirs views are passed asi parameter to `public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` as convertView.

This is first problem. List is **reusing** items.

2) Second thing is that AsyncTask is performed on another thread but more instances of **asyncTask are performed on the same thread**. it means they are performed **serially**. If you scroll quickly enough then you can make more requests on loading images with AsyncTask. At one time, there can be only few (i think 5) AsyncTask's jobs waiting in queue. Another ariving is ignored. So if you swipe quick enough you get this queue of 5 full and another image requests are **ignored**.

And this is It. You scroll, you start loading few images and the new displayed images are ignored. When you stop after while all AsyncTasks end and you got some "random" (previosly displaying) image loaded in your list item.

**Sollution**

This thing was discussed manny times and is solved. It is enough to use for example Picaso library:

https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc/

Comment: The picasso doesn't have explanation for making it possible with async calls. I see that they have URLs in place for the images. How to achieve that?

Comment: With picasso it is automaticly async =). Library is automaticly caching images (from internet or file system) and will reuse it. So you don't need to worry about that. Here is official site with examples: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). I will say it again: Don't do it YourSelf! Use library. Dont invent the wheel ;) If you are satisfied please accept answer

Comment: My doubt is how to get the images using Picasso, from a webservice. Image is placed in mysql db as blob type.

Comment: Storing images in db is rly bad pratcice. It is better to store it to filesystem with id of DB record. You can return image froms ervice as file (decode) it and then enter url address to that image in picaso http://example.com/my_image_123.png

Comment: What permission should I give to the image files created on server(LAMP). I am not able to view them.

Comment: Read permission shoud be enough for getting content (you need read permission for folder hierarchy). Firstly you can try to get image over browser so you are sure it is problem with getting image.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I am trying. But I am giving each new image 755 permission, then only I am able to view it.
Do you know how to give default permission to new files?
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

To add the answers, I would implement an image cache (e.g. as an URL-to-WeakReference-to-image hashmap). The `getView()` would access that cache and, if the image is not there, leave a request. When the image is loaded, the cache would examine the request list and notify the views that posted the requests (passing them both URL and the image). The views would compare the URL passed in notification to their current URL and either use the image or ignore it (if the view went out of screen or was reused, the image must be ignored).

Why request list. It is possible that multiple views manage to request some image and get reused before the image is loaded (especially if you scroll the list up and down several times).